# Difference in nuance between 미안하다, 죄송하다 and 송구하다

Tags: phrase-meaning

What message is conveyed by saying these different types of apologies in Korean:

**1. 미안하다**

**2. 죄송하다**

*and*

**3. 송구하다**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

미안 未安 means I'm worried.

죄송 罪悚 means I'm fearful (as if I committed a sin).

송구 悚懼 means I'm both worried and fearful.

So in terms of gravity 미안 < 죄송 < 송구 and you can sort of think of it like this.

> Ex. 1) You bump someone, then 미안합니다.

> Ex. 2) You bump someone and that person spills coffee on his/her shirt, then 죄송합니다.

> Ex. 3) You bump someone and that person falls down the stairs and you later visit him/her at the hospital, then 송구스럽습니다.

죄송합니다 is the most commonly used under any circumstances. 미안합니다 may feel a bit too light to be used with honorifics at all, and is typically said between friends and families as 미안해. 송구스럽습니다 is used at times but typically for actions that you take full responsibility for and are considered dire.